# Why does Magento keep only the first 1000 products in a category, after saving the category?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

Using Magento's back-office, after saving a category which was linked to many products, only the first 1000 products (or 2000, or x000, depending on host configuration) are kept.

All other category/product links are deleted from the `catalog_category_product` table in the database.
This occurs even though no checkboxes have been unchecked in the products grid (Category Products tab).

No error message is displayed or logged.
Tracing data posted from the browser to the server doesn't reveal any missing product IDs, but even if you check more products on the back-office grid, when finally saving the category, the server only keeps the first x000 and removes other IDs...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Though some answers can be found on other websites, I thought it was worth sharing this on StackOverflow...

The source of the problem can be found in `Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_CategoryController`, where the `saveAction()` method retrieves a big POSTed string (`category_products`, encoded like a query string), which is processed by PHP function `parse_str()`:

```
if (isset($data['category_products']) && !$category->getProductsReadonly()) {
    $products = array();
    parse_str($data['category_products'], $products);
    $category->setPostedProducts($products);
}
```

Alas! As from version 5.3.9 of PHP, there is a new configuration setting called `max_input_vars`, which limits the number of input variables that may be accepted.
This limit is mainly applied to `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE` superglobals, but is also used internally by the `parse_str()` function!
(See [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-var))

Depending on the `php.ini` configuration of your host, the number of products linked to a category is therefore limited by this setting...

**One solution** is to increase the value of `max_input_vars`, in `php.ini` or in `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value max_input_vars 10000
</IfModule>
```

This can even be done more safely by changing this setting only for admin pages (adapt the LocationMatch pattern to your own back-office URL style):

```
<LocationMatch "mymagentostore/(index\.php/)?admin/">
    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        php_value max_input_vars 10000
    </IfModule>
</LocationMatch>
```

([Source](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewreply/405627/))

This only solves the problem until one of your categories reaches the new max number of products...

**Another solution** would be to fix Magento's code in order *not* to use the parse_str() function at this point.
For instance, in `Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_CategoryController`, `saveAction()` method, replace:

```
parse_str($data['category_products'], $products);
```

with:

```
$cat_products_split = explode('&', $data['category_products']);
foreach($cat_products_split as $row) {
    $arr = array();
    parse_str($row, $arr); //This will always work
    list($k, $v) = each($arr);
    if (!empty($k) && !empty($v)) {
        $products[$k] = $v;
    }
}
```

([Source](https://gist.github.com/mshmsh5000/3440260))

It's hard to decide which solution is the best, since the first one makes your server more vulnerable to attacks (as the `max_input_vars` is meant to mitigate the possibility of denial of service attacks which use hash collisions), and the second solution makes you modify a Magento core class, which can lead to further problems in future Magento upgrades...

Hope this is useful anyway, I struggled some time before I could find out why some categories kept loosing some products!

Comment: Do you see a problem with increasing this to greater than 10,000?  We have some categories with over 31,000 products...

Comment: Well, I guess you can raise the limit to any number (yet, understanding that this makes your server more vulnerable to some DoS attacks).

Comment: For the second solution, couldn't you just override the controller from a custom module. This would make it upgrade safe since the core file remains unmodified.

Comment: @russjman look here for a complete implementation of solution 2:http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6319/impossible-to-save-category-with-more-that-1000-products

Comment: @programmeurweb:
your code for solution 2 is not working fine for me (don't know why but it was limiting the category size to 527 prod): I have 'fixed' your code ( it is almost equivalent )

Comment: Why should it resave all products every time you save any category property. The system would be smarter to detect that no category-product assocation was altered and save ONLY the easy-to-save category properties. Even after I use this fix, I expect that saving the `meta description` for a category will take 15 minutes.

Answer (score 5):

The best solution would be to use observer event "catalog_category_prepare_save".
So you need to change config.xml of you module:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <events>
            ...
            <catalog_category_prepare_save>
                <observers>
                    <your_module>
                         <class>your_module/observer</class>
                         <method>onCatalogCategoryPrepareSave</method>
                    </your_module>
                </observers>
            </catalog_category_prepare_save>
```

Then add function to app/code/local/Your/Module/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php
class Your_Module_Model_Observer
{
    /**
     * Fix bug with saving only first 1000 products in a category
     * It's related to default php config 'max_input_vars' = 1000
     *
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     */
     public function onCatalogCategoryPrepareSave(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
     {
         $phpDefaultMaxInputVars = (int)ini_get('max_input_vars');
        /** @var Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http $request */
        $request = $observer->getRequest();
        $dataProducts = $request->getPost('category_products');
        $dataProducts = preg_split('/&/', $dataProducts, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $category */
        $category = $observer->getCategory();

        if ($dataProducts && !$category->getProductsReadonly() && count($dataProducts) > $phpDefaultMaxInputVars) {
            $products = array();
            foreach ($dataProducts as $_product) {
                $_product = trim($_product);
                if (preg_match('/([0-9]*)=([\-]?[0-9]*)/', $_product, $matches)) {
                    $products[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
                }
            }
            $category->setPostedProducts($products);
        }
    }
}
```

([Source](https://gist.github.com/mshmsh5000/3440260#comment-1180382))

Answer (score 1):

I found a working solution so I am sharing it over here !

Create a file name `php5.ini` in your `magento root` folder and in the first line just place this code

```
[PHP]
max_input_vars = 5000
```

Now if its not working you will need to add this line in you SERVER PHP,ini (/usr/local/lib/php.ini)

```
max_input_vars = 5000
```

Hope its helping.

Answer (score 0):

`<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value max_input_vars 10000
</IfModule>`

did the trick for me, I had the same problem as described above, Magento 1.4.1.1 only saved 1001 products in the category, but after putting the code above in my .htaccess the bug is gone.

Answer (score 0):

**LocationMatch is not permitted in .htaccess, it can be only placed in Apache httpd.conf**

The prefered way is to create an Apache include and not modify httpd.conf directly as it would break on next updare/rebuild.

In my case I created an include file **pre_virtualhost_global.conf** and put this code inside:

```
<LocationMatch "mymagentostore/(index\.php/)?admin/">
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value max_input_vars 10000
</IfModule>
```

Afterwards of course, you need to restart apache. I used my WebHostManager so it was an easy process.

More info can be found at:

[http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/EasyApache3/WebHome#Custom Directives to http.conf][1]

I think this is the most elegant solution, doesn't touch Magento Core, applies to all sites on your server and also protects the frontend.

[1]: https://web.archive.org/web/20140804033608/http://docs.cpanel.net:80/twiki/bin/view/EasyApache3/WebHome?#Custom Directives to http.conf

Answer (score 0):

The solution 2 from programmeurweb is bugged, on Magento 1.8.0.0 !

```
if (!empty($k) && !empty($v)) {
    $products[$k] = $v;
}
```

It should be:

```
if (!empty($k)) {
    $products[$k] = $v;
}
```

$v is used for 'position' and is not a checkbox value = 1 (as associate product to current category checkbox).

I've tested this already.
Am I wrong ?

This reminds of never copy&paste code from net.

PS: I can't comment answers now.