# AJAX send all data but controller gets only part of it

Tags: php, magento, post, controller, request

I am using product custom options with many options in Magento 1.9.1.1.

The browser sends all of the values but the controller gets only some of them.
Why do not I get all the values?

I use standard AJAX and post methods to save the product.

```
$post = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();
```

I have `post_max_size = 100M` settings in my web server.

In browser:
[image]

In xDebug:
[image]

Comment: What is your `max_input_vars` setting? Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14851064/why-does-magento-keep-only-the-first-1000-products-in-a-category-after-saving-t

Comment: @RobbieAverill, in php.ini: " ; max_input_vars = 1000 "

Comment: Increase it to 10,000 or higher to see if that fixes your problem. Magento often sends thousands of post vars - especially when editing categories

Comment: @RobbieAverill its work! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `max_input_vars` in `php.ini` on web-server of PHP-FPM configuration to something higher than the default, e.g. 10,000.

Magento often sends more than [the default limit of 1000](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php), especially when editing categories.